# SVN not recognizing binary header changes

Tags: .net, svn, tortoisesvn

I have an issue where the header or meta data for a .net dll has changed but SVN (TSVN) isn't recognizing the binary has changed. I'm guessing it's the header or meta data, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Whats actually changed is that the version currently in the repository is not strongly named, but the version I want to commit is. I've check the strongly named settings using the `sn -Tp myAssembly.dll` command. There are no other changes to the code.

Comment: While not being an export on Windows development, I think it is safe to say that if svn does not report a difference for a file, the file is in fact *unchanged*. Are you sure that the header changes are in fact located in the dll file and not somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

See the FAQ entry [Why does TortoiseSVN not recognize that a file has been modified?](https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#detectmodification)

> Why does TortoiseSVN not recognize that a file has been modified?
>
> If you have modified a file, but TortoiseSVN does not recognize that
>   the file has been modified, please first check whether the file really
>   differs from what you have in your working copy.
>
> If you know for sure that the file has modifications and it still does
>   not show up as modified in the commit dialog, make sure that
>
> 1. the file 'last modification' date has changed (some tools like hex editors like to reset that time)
> 2. if the svn:eol-style property is set and the changes are only to newlines, the file won't show up as modified because for Subversion it
>      hasn't changed
>
> Subversion determines whether a file has changed with the following
>   approach:
>
> 1. has the 'last modification' date and/or the file size changed?
> 2. if not: file is not modified
> 3. if yes: compare file content with the BASE file
> 4. stop at the first byte that differs, mark the file as modified
> 5. if no byte differs regarding to BASE, mark the file as not-modified